# VBA executes code without error and does so properly when stepped through but not when running on its own

Tags: excel, vba

To start, I know this is a long post but I can't figure out where the issue lies and didn't want to have to keep updating everyone with code I didn't include so I included everything. Some code can be looked over as it poses no issue and I mention this to help make it quicker. Thanks a million.

Background: Howdy, y'all! At work we have a spreadsheet where users can select between 1 and 2 calculators to run some numbers and determine what the cost for an apartment should be. I was tasked with creating a SOP for the spreadsheet. I thought adding comments to different cells and then adding application.wait would be a good route to go so they could stay in the workbook VS having to be told and not shown via a Word document.

Issue: When I step through the macro, everything runs as it should. However, when I try to run through the program all at once, many of the lines of code aren't doing what I think they should be doing.

Here's the beginning of the code which works as expected...

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

MsgBox "This tour will auto play and show you how to go about using the Rate Calculator. Let's begin!"

'1 Selecting a calculator
Range("A2").AddComment
Range("A2").Comment.Visible = True
Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Start by selecting the type of rate calculator you would like to use. Do so by typing in your selection or using the drop down menu."
Range("A2").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
Range("A2").Comment.Delete
```

I have another sub that looks for event change in A2:A3 so I turn it on to allow this macro to run...

```
'2 After calculator selection
Application.EnableEvents = True
Range("A2").Value = "Match Lease"
Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A2").AddComment
Range("A2").Comment.Visible = True
Range("A2").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Once we've selected an option, 'Match Lease' in this case, the appropriate calculator becomes visible. Fill in the appropriate information in the gray boxes to obtain your daily rate."
Range("A2").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:09"))
Range("A2").Comment.Delete
```

The last three lines are where it starts to get wonky. The "once we've selected" comment appears but doesn't delete when it should. The upcoming code should then start displaying comments in F4. Instead, the activecell goes to F4, disappears, then adds the comment (unseen but you can see the red triangle). It waits some time then adds the red triangles in the next 3 rows as it should but without displaying the comments. Here's that rest of the code it doesn't do properly (including the F4 portion):

```
'3 Explain comments
Range("F4").AddComment
Range("F4").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F4").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Let's look at adding comments. At times you may need to provide a brief explanation of a cells contents. Right click in the appropriate cell then select 'Insert Comment'."
Range("F4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:...png").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 109.5
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 10.5
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
Range("F4").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Excel is not likely to size the box around your comments correctly. And at times, you may even have comments that overlap each other. Excel also requires the end-user " & Chr(10) & "to right-click each cell individually to show or hide comments in different cells. All of this is a piece of cake thanks to the buttons found below your 'Tour' button."
Range("F4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
Range("F4").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "I'm going to add a few comments to show you how they might look with no added effort other than adding and typing in the comment."
Range("F4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

Range("F5").AddComment
Range("F5").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F5").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "This is comment 1. This is comment 1."
Range("F6").AddComment
Range("F6").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F6").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "This is comment 2. This is comment 2."
Range("F7").AddComment
Range("F7").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F7").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Here's comment 3 but I can't see all of the two previous comments! I'm going to give you a little time to finish reading then I'll select the 'Autofit and Space All Comments Button'"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Call AutoFitAndAddSpaceToComments

Range("F4").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "What a relief! Who has time to re-adjust boxes all day? UPS maybe?"
Range("F4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
Range("F4").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Do you have comments that are in the way while you work and would like to hide them? Or do you have hidden comments you need to view? (*Comments need to be viewed in order to print*)" & Chr(10) & "Simply use the 'Show / Hide All Comments' button. I'll do that for you in a few moments..."
Range("F4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

Call ShowHideComments

MsgBox "Pretty cool, eh? Notice the red triangles in the cells? This means there's a comment in the cell. Hovering over it will display the message until you un-hover. Let's get rid of these comments and continue our tour!"
Call ShowHideComments
Range("F4").Comment.Delete
Range("F5").Comment.Delete
Range("F6").Comment.Delete
Range("F7").Comment.Delete
```

With the code above, we wanted to add 4 (unhidden) comments, add and delete a picture to show the right click menu, then delete the 4 comments. While it somewhat did (minus showing the comments), then it correctly fires the "Pretty cool" msgbox and deletes the F4:F7 comments. The next portion of code happens appropriately:

```
'4 Discuss helpful hints
Range("F27").AddComment
Range("F27").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F27").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "Notice that when your active cell is at F27 or F28, a tip is provided to remind you to select an option in the drop down to the left of your current, active cell."
Range("F27").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:11"))
Range("F27").Comment.Delete
```

The next section mostly works. It should display a comment in D41 and go back and forth between checking and unchecking two boxes two times, to help show the user where these boxes are. The first box gets checked, waits some time, then eventually unchecks it (but not twice and the second box never gets a checkmark.)

```
'5 Discuss checkboxes
Range("D41").AddComment
Range("D41").Comment.Visible = True
Range("D41").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "When you're done filling in all necessary gray boxes, place a checkmark in the appropriate box to indicate whether the client will be paying by check or credit card."
Range("D41").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 43").Value = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 43").Value = False
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 44").Value = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 44").Value = False
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 43").Value = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 43").Value = False
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 44").Value = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check box 44").Value = False
Range("D41").Comment.Delete
```

Finally we set a union of 2 noncontiguous ranges to display the cells we're referring to when letting the employee know that if any of them have a value, the "$ Amount (+/=)" field must be filled in prior to being able to print (handled via a beforeprint macro). While the union selection and event macro works, the adding of my comment in F102 does not.

```
'6 Explain printing won't work if table is partially filled out
With Sheets("Rate Calculator v6")
    Set rng1 = Range("A102:D102")
    Set rng2 = .Range("P102:Q102")
    Application.Union(rng1, rng2).Select
End With

Range("F102").AddComment
Range("F102").Comment.Visible = True
Range("F102").Comment.Text Text:= _
    "If any of the cells on this bottom table are filled in, Excel will not allow you to print until the '$ Amount (+/-)' field is entered."
Range("F102").Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:11"))
Range("F102").Comment.Delete
```

In case it's one of my called macros that's causing the issue, here's what I have:

```
Sub AutoFitAndAddSpaceToComments()
Dim rngComments As Range, cell As Range
Dim Cmt As Comment
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Cntr As Long
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
Set rngComments = Sheets("Rate Calculator v6").Range("F3:N46").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
If rngComments.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "There are no comments."

For Each cell In rngComments                                                                                        'Run through all comments and...
cell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True                                                                'autofit
Next cell

For Each cell In rngComments                                                                                    'Run through all comments and...
If BottomCntr > cell.Comment.Shape.Top Then cell.Comment.Shape.Top = BottomCntr + 2                     'If bottom of last comment is greater than the     top of current comment, add 2 points
TopCntr = cell.Comment.Shape.Top
HeightCntr = cell.Comment.Shape.Height
BottomCntr = TopCntr + HeightCntr
'Debug.Print cell.Comment.Shape.Name; " Top:"; TopCntr; " Height:"; HeightCntr; " Bottom:"; BottomCntr
Next cell
ActiveSheet.Protect "password", "false"
End Sub


Sub ShowHideComments()
If Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly Then
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
Else
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've debugged this problem in the past, I'm trying to remember what the solution was. Basically, there is a (tiny, minor) difference between running the code in break mode, and running the code 'normally'. You have some selects in place, are you sure that when you're running the code in break mode that you start on the same page that you'd call the code from?

Comment: My first thoughts involve Application.Wait. This may make a difference to execution in real-time versus stepping through. Try commenting out all your Application.Wait lines and then running the comparison again.

Comment: @Selkie Yes, I only keep one sheet visible so I only start it here. There will actually be a button to run this macro as well to ensure it's only fired from the correct sheet. Chris: I'd considered it could be the waits so I tried to just skip them in one of my tests but only by moving the active line arrow in VBA to skip it. I'll give it a go commenting out all the wait times and see what I can find. Thanks you two!

Comment: In regards to taking out the application.waits, the program ran but so fast that I couldn't determine what happened really. I tried looking up some ways around application.wait and found a few loops that didn't help. I then stumbled upon https://analystcave.com/vba-sleep-vs-wait/ and although I don't quite get what DoEvents does besides nothing, I replaced all my application.waits with DoEvents and some of what I wasn't seeing is now showing but conversely, some of what was working is now not working. Going to try a combination of application.wait and doevents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the sleep feature in place of application.wait and had much better success. Thanks for the suggestions! http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/examples/avoiddoevents.asp